# How to use @Embedded with List in Spring Boot REST

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping, spring-rest

There are multiple records for an item and that needs to be stored in same table.

How can I use `@Embedded` annotation for `List<SomeClassName> someclassName;`

```
@Entity
public class Child {

@Embedded
List<SomeClassName> someclassName;
/** 
* other code .....
*
/
}
```

Snippet example for JSON looks like below :

```
{
  "main": {
    "child": [
      {
        "list": [
          {
            "item1": "string",
            "item2": "string"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your business logic, you can't store multiple items in the same table. You can use ***@ElementCollection*** to map non-entities and ***@OneToMany*** for map entities, both require an additional table.